# Extracting only the value out of a json with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I try to do this:

**.js:**

```
app.controller('appControler', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get(apiBaseURL + "getMyName")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myName = response.data;
  });
});
```

**.html:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder={{myName}}
style="width:106%;" input disabled>
</div>
```

What I receive in the web is this:

```
{"getMyName":"Test Name"}
```

What I want is only this:

```
Test Name
```

What Im missing here?

Comment: `$scope.myName = response.data.getMyName;` ?

Comment: Use `{{myName.getMyName}}`

Comment: @charlietfl thx works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Dot Operator **`{{myName.getMyName}}`**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder={{myName.getMyName}}
style="width:106%;" input disabled>
```